# VirtualBox - Different subnets on the same network

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualbox, routing, subnets

I have several virtual machines which are running in VirtualBox. Ubuntu Server 18.04 is installed on host. All of them are using "Host-Only Guest". Also Internet is working through "Host-Only Adapter".

For a number of reasons, I set not local, but public IP addresses for virtual machines. That is, for example, the host and guest do not have 192.168.56.1 and 192.168.56.100, as is usually the case, but, for example, 11.22.33.1 and 11.22.33.44, respectively. An even more detailed explanation. The virtual machine's gateway is not 192.168.56.1, but 11.22.33.1. And it even works. The host and guest can communicate with each other and the virtual machine can even access the Internet.

In order for the virtual machine to be able to access the Internet and accept connections, I made the following script for each virtual machine. Example:

```bash
localinterface=vboxnet0

# hosts's interface
publicinterface=ppp1

# public ip
localip=34.56.78.90

# local gateway
maingateway=10.0.3.1

# host's local ip
mainip=10.0.3.10

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s $localip/32 -o $publicinterface -j SNAT --to-source $mainip
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $publicinterface -p tcp --dport 1:65534 -j DNAT --to-destination $localip
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $publicinterface -p udp --dport 1:65534 -j DNAT --to-destination $localip
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $publicinterface -p gre -j DNAT --to-destination $localip
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p icmp -d $mainip -j DNAT --to-destination $localip
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -p icmp -d $localip -j ACCEPT

ip rule add from $localip table vm2
ip route add default dev $publicinterface via $maingateway table vm2
```

I understand that by doing this, neither the host nor any of the guests will have access to the REAL machine that has the IP address 34.56.78.90, but that's not what I care about.

The problem is that although the VMs are on the same network (vboxnet0), they cannot communicate with each other. I'm sure this is because the hosts have different subnets. traceroute and ping don't even give any results. Then I tried to register the following routes:

```bash
ip route add 99.88.77.0/24 via 11.22.33.1 dev vboxnet0 table vm0
ip route add 34.56.78.0/24 via 11.22.33.1 dev vboxnet0 table vm0

ip route add 11.22.33.0/24 via 99.88.77.1 dev vboxnet0 table vm1
ip route add 34.56.78.0/24 via 99.88.77.1 dev vboxnet0 table vm1

ip route add 11.22.33.0/24 via 34.56.78.1 dev vboxnet0 table vm2
ip route add 99.88.77.0/24 via 34.56.78.1 dev vboxnet0 table vm2
```

Some progress has already begun, but it has not yet brought the desired result. After that, if you try to traceroute from one virtual machine to another, it reaches its gateway and hangs there

```
root@ubuntu-server-1804-fastpanel:~# traceroute -n 99.88.77.66
traceroute to 99.88.77.66 (99.88.77.66), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  11.22.33.1  0.222 ms  0.400 ms  0.334 ms^C
root@ubuntu-server-1804-fastpanel:~#
```

Also the ping command started showing that the gateway was redirecting to another host

```
root@ubuntu-server-1804-fastpanel:~# ping 99.88.77.66
PING 99.88.77.66 (99.88.77.66) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 11.22.33.1: icmp_seq=2 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 99.88.77.66)
From 11.22.33.1: icmp_seq=3 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 99.88.77.66)
From 11.22.33.1: icmp_seq=4 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 99.88.77.66)
From 11.22.33.1: icmp_seq=5 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 99.88.77.66)
From 11.22.33.1: icmp_seq=6 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 99.88.77.66)
^C
--- 99.88.77.66 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 6066ms

root@ubuntu-server-1804-fastpanel:~#
```

Now my routes on the host look like this

```
root@hypervisor:~# ip route
default via 10.0.1.1 dev eth0 proto static 
default via 10.0.2.1 dev ppp0 proto static 
default via 10.0.3.1 dev ppp1 proto static 
10.0.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.1.10 
10.0.2.1 dev ppp0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.10 
10.0.3.1 dev ppp1 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.3.10 
10.27.137.0/24 dev vboxnet0 proto kernel scope link src 10.27.137.213 
34.56.78.0/24 dev vboxnet0 proto kernel scope link src 34.56.78.1 
11.22.33.0/24 dev vboxnet0 proto kernel scope link src 11.22.33.1 
99.88.77.0/24 dev vboxnet0 proto kernel scope link src 99.88.77.1 
root@hypervisor:~# ip route show table vm0 && ip rule show table vm0
default via 10.0.1.1 dev eth0 
34.56.78.0/24 via 11.22.33.1 dev vboxnet0 
99.88.77.0/24 via 11.22.33.1 dev vboxnet0 
199:    from 11.22.33.44 lookup vm0 
root@hypervisor:~# ip route show table vm1 && ip rule show table vm1
default via 10.0.2.1 dev ppp0 
34.56.78.0/24 via 99.88.77.1 dev vboxnet0 
11.22.33.0/24 via 99.88.77.1 dev vboxnet0 
97:     from 99.88.77.66 lookup vm1 
99:     from 99.88.77.66 lookup vm1 
root@hypervisor:~# ip route show table vm2 && ip rule show table vm2
default via 10.0.3.1 dev ppp1 
11.22.33.0/24 via 34.56.78.1 dev vboxnet0 
99.88.77.0/24 via 34.56.78.1 dev vboxnet0 
96:     from 34.56.78.90 lookup vm2 
98:     from 34.56.78.90 lookup vm2 
root@hypervisor:~#
```

What do I need to do in my case so that hosts that have different subnets, but are on the same network, can communicate with each other?